# What would be a good timeout value for locks in when using NHibernate.Caches.Redis?

Tags: caching, nhibernate, redis

We're currently using the [NHibernate.Caches.Redis](https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/NHibernate.Caches.Redis) project which uses a number of locks when acquiring data. We've noticed that the default lock timeout is 30 seconds, which seems like a long time to wait to acquire a lock and we're getting a lot of timeouts in the logs when a lock fails, so we're considering lowering the value... but we're not sure to what.

Is anyone able to provide some advice on what a good timeout value would be and the potential side effects of lowering the locks timeout value on performance?

Comment: Not sure Stack Overflow is a good fit, or otherwise question likely to be too broad, even with more details like this [other one](/q/41893459/1178314). Such question may call for a discussion about how to choose a timeout, which is more a discussion on a general concept. In such case https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com could be a better fit.

Comment: @Frédéric when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat, of course this implies deleting the question here (or migrating it) if the OP agrees on the fact it is currently not on the right site. I usually expect a 10k+ user to know this.

Answer (score 0):

So the question above may have been a bit broad, but posting here for posterity in the hopes that it'll help someone in future.

We were getting a lot of locking in our NHibernate caches which were causing subsequent timeouts - hence the question above.

To resolve the issue, we disabled QueryCache and reduced the scope of what we were caching in the L2 cache.

QueryCache causes all sorts of issues with locking (more details [here](http://puredanger.github.io/tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/)). 
Disabling QueryCache resolved the issue.